# Javascript do something before alert

Tags: javascript

I want to change the color and alert a message when a button is clicked.

```
function colorChange() {
  document.getElementById('word').style.color = "red";
  alert("color changed!");
}
```

I cannot change the color at the same time with an alert.

Comment: Wrap the alert in a timeout, and it will work, but why do you need it, surely you aren't using alerts for anything ?

Comment: I will do something after the alert has been answered, but I gotta figure out this problem first. Thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrap the alert in a timeout

```js
function colorChange() {
  document.getElementById('word').style.color = "red";
  setTimeout(function() {
   alert("color changed!");
  },10)
}
```

```html
<div id="word">
Word .....
</div>
<br />
<button onclick="colorChange()">
Change color
</button>
```

The browser doesn't have time to repaint before the alert fires, by using a timeout you delay the alert until the next tick, when the repaint has completed.

Comment: But it is not immediately response with the alert box. I mean I changed the value 10 to 1, but it sometimes won't work.

Comment: @namnam0107 - How long the browser needs to repaint can vary, but the only way to do this, as far as I know, is to delay the alert giving the browser time to repaint, and waiting 0.010 seconds is probably the price you pay for doing this.

Comment: So when I keep pressing the button, the color may not be changed sometimes?

Comment: That's a possibility, yes, and would happen if the browser doesn't have time to repaint before the alert blocks it. There's no way around that, other than increasing the timeout

Comment: Without the async keyword being used, why does it process it as if it's async? Being single-threaded language, I don't understand why it would behave as if it's an async function.  Please, if someone could explain. I don't suppose theirs a keyword that can be used akin to async but opposite to ensure it doesn't behave in this manner since a hardcoded value, even a large one doesn't guarantee that the styling will complete first.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is using the Window.requestAnimationFrame().

```
function colorChange() {
    document.getElementById('word').style.color = "red";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => 
        {window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>
            alert("color changed!");})
}
```

requestAnimationFrame is called before the next browser repaint. This guarantees that the browser will repaint it before the alert. This is better practice than guessing the number of seconds before the next paint.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame