# Playing a sound while an alert is displayed

Tags: javascript, html

I need a sound to play while or before a score alert pops up (simple dinosaur game). Right now it just shows the alert and then it plays the sound. I have tried to set a timeout but it doesn't work.

```js
if (blockLeft < 200 && blockLeft > 0 && characterTop >= 300) {
    const death = new Audio((URL = "/sound/death.mp3"));
    death.play();
    death.volume = 0.4;
    block.style.animation = "none";
    block.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(
      alert("Totaler Absturz. Score: " + Math.floor(counter / 100)),
      5000
    );
    counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript do something before alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724697/javascript-do-something-before-alert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the timeout a function. It needs to say:

```js
setTimeout(
  () => alert("Totaler Absturz. Score: " + Math.floor(counter / 100)),
  5000
);
```

It's the `() => ...` bit that will wrap your alert in a function. If it's not wrapped in a function, it will execute immediately.

Gruß

Comment: I put in the function that plays the sound (exactly how you suggested) and it still sends the alert before the sound plays. Gruß

Comment: How large of a file is the mp3/how long does it take to load it?

Comment: the audio file has a size of 50KB and it plays immediatly after I click ok on the alert

Comment: hey man I managed to get it to work. turned out github took a bit to load everything.. Im still trying to figure out how everything works yk. have nice day