# How can I remove innerHTML of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, element

I write some JS code to change name. When I click on the button I expect the old name to disappear, however, the code ignore the first line and go on to the alert box part. I don't know what wrong with my logic. Please help me.

```js
function changeName() {
  var element = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (element != "") {
    element.innerHTML = "";
  }
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var nameChange = " ";
  if (name.length < 2) {
    alert("You need a longer name!");
  } else {
    nameChange =
      name.charAt(name.length - 1) +
      name.slice(1, name.length - 1) +
      name.charAt(0);
    element.innerHTML = "Your new name is " + nameChange;
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Enter your name:</p>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <button onclick="changeName()">Change Name</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code seems to work fine for me. The alert is probably appearing before the page has time to redraw.

Comment: The code seems to work fine (even before the edits)

Comment: The name disappears after you dismiss the alert. Are you expecting it to disappear first?

Comment: Are you expecting the value of the input to get emptied? Also, `if (element != "") {` should just be `if (element) {` it will never be an empty string.

Comment: This might be a perhaps better answer than the `setTimeout` https://stackoverflow.com/a/75608120/125981 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/56260606/125981

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("demo") will return either the element (if it exists) or null (if it doesn't exist). You should check if the element is not null instead:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("demo");
if (element) {
  element.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Try using this function:

```js
function changeName() {
  var element = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (element) {
    element.innerHTML = "";
  }
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var nameChange = " ";
  if (name.length < 2) {
    alert("You need a longer name!");
  } else {
    nameChange =
      name.charAt(name.length - 1) +
      name.slice(1, name.length - 1) +
      name.charAt(0);
    element.innerHTML = "Your new name is " + nameChange;
  }
}
```

Comment: While true this is not the root cause of the observed behavior